# Laravel query. Where unique

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I got database table like this:

```
**job_id**
    5
    5
    5
    6
    6
    7
    8
    8
```

I want to write query, which could select only unique id's. By saying unique I mean select only these values once:
`5, 6, 7, 8`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code have you written to solve this problem? Please post your code and a (specific) problem.

Comment: At the moment my query picks all the job_id's. So when I do echo, my values doublicate. I want to echo these job_id's only once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
$jobs = DB::table('my_job_table')
    ->groupBy('job_id')
    ->get();
```

Eloquent:

1. First, you need a model. You could generate this by using php artisan. `php artisan make:model jobs` (I assume you have done this already) This will create a model in /your_project/app/Job.php
2. Now you can use Eloquent (here in a route, to see some output):

   `Route::get('/jobs', function () {
       $jobs = \App\Job::groupBy('job_id')->get();
       return $jobs->lists('job_id');
   });`

will return something like: `[0,1,3,4]` instead of `[0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4]`.

Comment: How do I do this with eloquent?

Comment: @EvaldasButkus exactly the same way

Answer (score 15):

You could use **[DISTINCT](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)**.

```
DB::table('table')->select('job_id')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: How do I do this with eloquent?

Comment: @EvaldasButkus exactly the same way